# double screen 1 fullscreen

Tags: 13.04, fullscreen

I hook up my Laptop running ubuntu 13.10 to my TV using a HDMI cable the thing is that I would like to work as I watch a Movie, but when I click on the screen on the laptop, I stop getting a fullscreen movie on my TV, is there a way to fix this?

tx in advance